# ros add third party library but compilation does not pass

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to load third party library ，but  compilation does not pass .How to solve it.
**my cmakefile.txt:**

```
ink_directories(${catkin_LIB_DIRS} lib)
add_executable( testusbcan src/testusbcan.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(testusbcan ${catkin_LIBRARIES} controlcan)
include_directories(/home/exbot/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/include/head )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testusbcan -lcontrolcan)
```

**terminal displayed：**

```
CMakeFiles/testusbcan.dir/src/testusbcan.cpp.o: In function `main':
testusbcan.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `VCI_OpenDevice(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/exbot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/testusbcan] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/testusbcan.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
exbot@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273214/ros-add-third-party-library-but-compilation-does-not-pass/) by [s201761315](https://answers.ros.org/users/32274/s201761315/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that `VCI_OpenDevice` is in `libcontrolcan.so`. What directory is `libcontrolcan.so` located?

CMake's `link_directories(...)` macro resolves relative paths from the source directory ([reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html)). Is `<package_path>/lib/` the directory that contains `libcontrolcan.so`? If not, you'll have to provide the full path to that directory. Hardcoding a full path is a fragile solution, so I suggest you read about [How to Find Libraries in CMake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0